C++ server/client application: robust communication through NFS
I have an C++ application client/server which communicates through NFS filesystem on two different machines.
The server appends the messages it wants to send in a file (messages.txt) and creates a dummy file (.dummy) to notify the client there are some new messages to read in messages.txt.
Then, regularly (every minute), the client checks the presence of this .dummy file. If it is present, it reads the new messages and deletes the .dummy file. We can consider that the server sends at least one message per minute.
This works globally fine but I had one case where the client never detected the presence of .dummy file (during +24h). When debugging this, a simple 'ls' (external to the application and performed on the server machine) in the directory made the client detect the presence of this dummy file and unblocked the communication.
I tried to reproduce this scenario but without success.
The detection of the dummy file is done with:
boost::filesystem::exists(dummyFile);

Which seems to be translated into: open("/.dummy", O_RDONLY)
So, I am wondering if it is a NFS cache issue (I am still not very clear about that - a clear explanation would be welcome) and if doing something as below would make the application more robust to detect the presence of the file on the client side:
auto files = boost::make_iterator_range(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir), {});
for (const auto& entry : files) {
    if (entry.path() == dummyFile) {
        return true;
    }
}

Which seems to be translated into:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<dir>", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
getdents(3, [{d_ino=15851, d_off=10, d_reclen=24, d_name=".", d_type=DT_DIR}, {d_ino=67160780, d_off=12, d_reclen=24, d_name="..", d_type=DT_DIR}, {d_ino=468177, d_off=512, d_reclen=24, d_name=".dummy", d_type=DT_REG}], 32768) = 72

Also, on server side, if the server wants to send new messages and the .dummy file is already there (meaning that the client has already some messages to read), the .dummy file is left unchanged.
I am wondering if changing its attributes or deleting+recreating it would help.

Robust communication and using files is IMO a contradiction. There is just no good way to do error handling. e.g does a file not appearing (within a timeframe) incdicate some error or is the network just slow? (you can't tell). So no don't use files as an interprocess communication mechanism. I recommend using an RPC mechanism instead. (e.g. gRPC)

Thanks @PepijnKramer. RPC would require that some ports between client and server machines are open (http2 port), no? I can't make this assumption because I do not know the network rules at the customer's.

Yes that would require some port numbers. Are the client and server on the same (V)LAN? And both developed by you? If so the server can lookup a free port number. And then client can send an UDP broadcast packet requesting the server information (ip address + port number). If the server receives such a packet it can send the info on its IP+port back to the client which can then connect.

I'd look into RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, or the like

This is almost certainly a caching issue. NFS clients tend to do pretty heavy caching, since network requests are so expensive. You can verify this by making a packet capture while your application is running. You'll see if the exists(dummyfile) call triggers a network request.

Thanks for these answers. How can I mitigate this caching effect? Is that more robust to list all the entries of the directory instead of doing a fstat of the file?
